# SOL help in QGIS: rule based styling to show timestamp increase via gradient

Tags: qgis, sql, color-ramp, rule-based

I have some polygon data from a tractor that shows it's route among other things. It has a timestamp column which I'd like to use to show the route in which the tractor drove through the field via a color ramp (other suggestions?).

I'm a novice at best with SQL and I don't know how to code it. I have about 41,000 datapoints in the table, which turns out to be around 12 hours.

How do I code for a color ramp that increases as the values in the timestamp column increase.

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/197503/edit) your question to include an example (or screenshot) of what your timestamp looks like in your table? E.g. `10am`, `10:00`, `2016-06-08T10:00:00`...

Comment: I know you are using QGIS, but this could be done very easy with **CartoDB**. **Torque Maps** allows you to visualize animated data according to a timestamp column. [Here](https://team.cartodb.com/u/javi/viz/7a99951e-aba7-11e3-b843-0e10bcd91c2b/embed_map) you have a working example and [here](https://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/heatmap/) a basic tutorial.